# how to convert jar file into .dmg on windows

Tags: java, macos, dmg

I have developed a JavaFX project on Windows and now I want to convert jar file to Dmg file to run on mac. Please recommend a tool that runs on Windows and can create a DMG file for a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply install the free trial of [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/software/macdrive/) on your windows machine  and follow these steps :

1. Make a new folder and move all your jars and dependencies into it.
2. Go to applications->Utilities->Disk utility.
3. Select "New Image from folder" and select your folder.